# js function is called without clicking on button

Tags: javascript, button

have the problem, that the function is called before clicking the button3. how can i solve that mistake and why button3 doesnt work? o_O cant find my fail in that code. thx

```js
Buttons()

function Buttons() {
  var buttonDivs = document.getElementById('Buttons')
  var buttons = document.createElement('input')
  buttons.setAttribute('type', 'button')
  buttons.setAttribute('name', 'button3')
  buttons.setAttribute('value', 'button3')
  buttons.setAttribute('id', 'btn');
  buttons.onclick = function3('button3');
  buttonDivs.appendChild(buttons)
}

function function3(something) {
  console.log('hello' + something)
}
```

```html
<div id="Buttons">
  <button onclick="function3('test1')">Button1</button>
  <button onclick="function3('test2')">Button2</button>
  <br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you're calling the function instead of passing it, call `function3` inside the `onclick` function like :

```
buttons.onclick = function(){ function3('button3') };
```

```js
Buttons()

function Buttons() {
  var buttonDivs = document.getElementById('Buttons')
  var buttons = document.createElement('input')
  buttons.setAttribute('type', 'button')
  buttons.setAttribute('name', 'button3')
  buttons.setAttribute('value', 'button3')
  buttons.setAttribute('id', 'btn');
  buttons.onclick = function(){ function3('button3') };
  buttonDivs.appendChild(buttons)
}

function function3(something) {
  console.log('hello' + something)
}
```

```html
<div id="Buttons">
  <button onclick="function3('test1')">Button1</button>
  <button onclick="function3('test2')">Button2</button>
  <br><br><br><br>
</div>
```